# Как узнать высоту элемента включая скрытую часть

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, css3

Мне требуется получить высоту элемента, который частично находится в видимой зоне, а частично скрыт (т. е. требуется пролистать сайт, чтобы увидеть его)

При использовании JQuery `height()` и `clientHeight` из ванильного JS даётся только видимая часть элемента.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 2):

Высота блока 118px (`20px padding-top` + `78px height` + `20px padding-bottom`)

```js
let block = document.querySelector('.block');
console.log(`${block.offsetHeight}px`);
```

```css
.block {
  height: 78px;
  width: 78px;
  background: #222;
  color: #eee;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
Скрольте вниз
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="block"> I am block!</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
```